# Virtualization performance after Windows reinstall

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, performance

I have a laptop with core i7 7700hq, 16gb RAM, 512 GB PCI-e SSD.
Perfomance of virtual machines was great. Android emulators through genymotion were blindingly fast, windows guests on virtual box, mac os guests on virtual box were fine too. I had an old Windows 10 which wasn't updated for a long time and couldn't for some reason.
I've installed new Windows 10 from Microsoft's Media Creation Tool.
And suddenly everything is painfully slow. Not only VirtualBox, but also Visual Studio's Android emulator. All of them slower, I think, by 10 times!

I've checked BIOS to make sure virtualization is still enabled.

Selected high performance mode in Windows's Power Settings.

HAXM is installed too.

VirtualBox says "VTx is Active".

Visual Studio's Android emulator says HAXM is active and running at full speed.

I don't know what else to check. Any ideas?

Comment: You have way to many Hypervisors enabled and VirtualBox and Hyper-V shouldn't both be installed.  " I think, by 10 times!" - Please in specific detail indicated how you performed this benchmark.  I assume VT-x and VT-d are both enabled?  Update your question.  Uninstall VirtualBox and see what sort of performance you get with your Hyper-V VMs (i.e. the Android emulator).

Answer (score 0):

It was goddamned Avast. Even disabling virtualization in its settings did not help! Only after full uninstall everything went back to normal. As I understand, AVG may cause same issues. I'll stick with Windows Defender from now on.